# Cannot run program in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I've recently made an app and could successfully run and test it until this suddenly happened,

[fail to run program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxQ2r.png)

It doesn't looks like an issue, but the "run" button is unavailable. Usually it should look something like,

[successfully run a program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqqJW.png)

As in the image, first there are two buttons, run and stop, after that there is the name of the program/app and its icon (fun facts) and then the iphone simulator it will run on (iphone 6). On the image on top, the failed to run program attempt, it is totally different, first the run button is disabled, second, the icon is a gear and not the app icon, and third, there is no simulator, it appears "my mac".

I don't know why this happened but this cannot let me run the app. I searched in the apple documentation and didn't found anything. If someone knows how to solve this please tell me.

Comment: Can you change *My Mac* to an iPhone device/simulator by pressing on it?

Comment: Or press on the algorythm field and select the APP?

Comment: No, usually it would show the whole iphone simulator palette but it just shows _My mac_

Comment: And on the algorithm part it also just shows algorythm

Comment: Did you recently try to rename your project?

Comment: Yes, I think maybe it's because of that

Comment: Yep, well, in older versions of Xcode there is a bug where doing that will hose your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to rebuild your project from scratch. This is not difficult because you still have all your code. So, start with a new project from the iOS template. Copy your code from the old project into the new project.

And try to avoid renaming your project from now on, because there is a bug in some versions of Xcode where it crashes and destroys the project in just the way you describe in your question.

And update to the latest version of Xcode, because it is less likely to cause this problem (though in fact I have not found it reliable for renaming projects even now).

Comment: The same happened to me without renaming. But I +1 since the advice to assemble everything afresh always works )